# Where can I find source code of physics glossary android application?

Tags: android

I am new in android application development. I have basic knowledge in java. I want to develop an app of glossary of terms with figures. How should I approach? Shall I use SQLite Database for this? Where can i find the Sqlite database application examples with source code.

thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html ?

For a dictionary app, see: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Comment: yes ..I have looked at those samples.  In dictionary app all the words are stored in txt file. Wanted to look some glossary applications with images.can you help me please?

Comment: You can look at the notebook example for how to use an sql db. Start coding, and when you have a specific question, you can post it here.